# Supporting a Delta Lake-like format in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I usually use Parquet to [load data into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data) as a starting point, as with the compression and support it seems to be the best fit when compared with other formats, such as JSON, CSV, Avro, and ORC (at least in our tests of it).

However, I'm wondering if it's possible to attain a sort of [Delta Lake](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/quick-start.html)-like quality so that we can use Parquet perhaps as a starting point and then some other stored file(s) to process a transaction log of modifications to the data (Insert, Update, Delete), particularly the Update and Delete operations. We can use the streaming/storage-write API, but we'd also like the ability to re-play the data if we ever need to snapshot or rollback the data.

I suppose I'm basically looking for something like a "File-ingest" plus "CDC-log" for data ingestion. Is there a file-only architecture that could support this?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/biglake

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant not really, that just does cross-cloud, it doesn't have much to do with delta file formats, unless I'm missing something (if so please tell me).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that right now there is such an option with a file-only using just BigQuery. Not too familiar with Delta Lake, but since seems to work with spark you may use something like data proc to emulate that kind of Architecture.

Here you can find a link to the implementation of DeltaLake using GCP.

[image]

https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/how-build-open-cloud-datalake-delta-lake-presto-dataproc-metastore